# iOS7's deprecation of NSString's drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, ios7, deprecated

With iOS7's release, the following function has been deprecated:

```
drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:
```

In Apple's documentation it suggests to use

```
drawInRect:withAttributes:
```

The reason I use this function is because of the `<code>minFontSize</code>` parameter, which lets me draw a string inside a rect.

If the text won't fit, it will first shrink the text size to `<code>minFontSize</code>` and then if it doesn't fit, it will truncate it.

I am unable to accomplish this so far using `<code>drawInRect:withAttributes:</code>`.

Which key I can use to determine the `<code>minFontSize</code>` equivalent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a little more complicated than before and you cannot use a minimum font size, but have to use minimum font scale factor. There is also a bug in the iOS SDK, which breaks it for most use cases (see notes at the bottom). Here is what you have to do:

```
// Create text attributes
NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]};

// Create string drawing context
NSStringDrawingContext *drawingContext = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
drawingContext.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5; // Half the font size

CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 100.0);
[string drawWithRect:drawRect
             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
          attributes:textAttributes
             context:drawingContext];
```

**Notes:**

- There seems to be a bug in the iOS 7 SDK at least up to version 7.0.3: If you specify a custom font in the attributes, the miniumScaleFactor is ignored. If you pass nil for the attributes, the text is scaled correctly.
- The `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` option is important. It tells the text drawing system, that the drawing rect's origin should be at the top left corner.
- There is no way to set the baselineAdjustment using the new method. You would have to do that yourself by calling `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` first and then adjusting the rect before you pass it to `drawWithRect:options:attributes:context`.

Comment: According to the documentation, your answer is correct. However, as you indicate, there seems to be a bug and this is getting ignored. I didn't try your suggestion of leaving attributes nil, since I do require to pass in some attributes, or the returned size will be incorrect anyway. I'm marking this answer as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After googling for a long time I did not find a solution working under iOS7.

Right now I use the following workaround, knowing that it is very ugly.

I render a UILabel in memory, take a screenshot and draw that.

UILabel is able to shrink the text correctly.

Perhaps someone finds it useful.

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myLabelFrame];
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic" size:16];
myLabel.text = @"Some text that is too long";
myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myLabelFrame.size, NO, 0.0f);
[[myLabel layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[screenshot drawInRect:myLabel.frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

just create an NS dictionary with that key and attribute so it would be

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"15", @"minFontSize", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
//in key2 and value2 you could set any other of the attributes included in the first method
[yourString drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
```

Comment: adding minFontSize as a key doesn't really change anything.

Comment: yep, sorry, i didn't read your question correctly, I couldn't find any key in the documentation that does exactly what minFontSize would do, but maybe playing with this key would work, "NSStrokeWidthAttributeName" , hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to solve my problem. 
Using the below code you can drawAtPoint, set font, font size and font color at a X , Y location.

[String drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(X, Y)
          withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:199.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:54.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] }];

Comment: Add some additional context to this answer to help people understand why this is a good answer, rather than just posting raw code.